# Blender render problems

Tags: rendering

Does anyone knows why my final blender render looks like that? In the preview all looks fine.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Blender SE! This looks like (another) overlapping faces problem. Do you have multiple faces with different textures on top of each other?

Comment: maybe you have forgotten to disable the render of another version of your car? Check the Outliner

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

Check your Outliner. An old car you may have been working on may not be visible in the viewport, but is visible in renders only.

In the Outliner, the Eye is for visible in viewport, the Camera is for visible in a render.

In this picture, I have 4 objects.
Camera is visible in the viewport and in a render.
CameraTarget is not visible in the viewport, but is visible in a render.
TriLamp-Back is visible in the viewport, but not in a render.
TriLamp-Fill is not visible in the viewport, nor in a render.

[image: Outliner View]

Comment: Although you explained the meaning of the settings quite good, if one had exactly this scene and would try to see the effect on rendered images it would hardly be showing the problem... since cameras, empties and lights are always invisble in the render. Well, of course lights would illuminate things which makes a difference and you could make them visible in render if you change their default settings... but I mean, the objects themselves are not visible and would never cause such strange behaviour shown in the question. But I'm just nit-picky ;)

Comment: True @GordonBrinkmann, I just picked the most lightweight objects in my scene to show/hide. And then I ended up forgetting I turned the lights off and had dimly lit renders lol

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to disable the *Shrinkwrap* modifier faces from the render. All works now. [image]